# Dynamically Update Model From Web Socket

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Update (High Level Idea/Concept)

To summarize I would like values to be dynamically updated in a controller which is binded to a Web Socket Service, which value change. Below is my attempt of how to solve the problem and the barrier which I am facing.

---

I would like to update the view model in the controller, each time that the socket pushes information in the service. To mimic the pushing of messages I am just calling a timeout every second, which in turn increase the value of health within the service, which I verified it works in console.

Though the value of the health within controller is never updated, and I am at a loss of of what I am doing wrong. Below are the snippets of relatable code.

This is the controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('xxx')
        .controller('DashboardController', ['$scope','$timeout', "$uibModal", "dashboardService", "syncService", DashboardController]);

    function DashboardController($scope, $timeout, $uibModal, dashboardService, syncService) {
        var vm = this;

        // VERSIONS
        vm.versions = {};

        // HEALTH
        vm.health= syncService.health;

        // JUMP-START
        activate();

        //////////////

        function activate(){
           getVersions();
        }

        function getVersions(){
            dashboardService.getVersions()
                         .then(function(data) {
                            vm.versions = data;
                            return vm.versions;
                         });
        }

    }
})();
```

This is the service

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';
        angular
            .module('xxx')
            .service('syncService',['$timeout', syncService]);

        function syncService($timeout) {
            //Init WebSocket
            var self = this;
            self.health= 0;
            updatedStatus();
            ///////////

            ....

        function updatedStatus(){
            $timeout(updatedStatus, 1000);
            self.health += 1;
            $timeout(angular.noop);   
        };
    }
})();
```

---

Update

---

I would like to know how to make it work **without** using $scope. Example like in the accepted answer in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337839/websocket-service-update-scope-in-angular-using-ngwebsocket)

thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/angularjs-how-to-watch-service-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you'll need to put a watch on the service variable. This is what I did to get this to work:

```
  function DashboardController($scope, $timeout, $uibModal, dashboardService, syncService) {
    var vm = this;

    // VERSIONS
    vm.versions = {};

    // HEALTH
     vm.syncService = syncService;

     $scope.$watch('vm.syncService.health', function(newHealth, oldHealth){
        vm.health = newHealth;
     })

    // JUMP-START
    activate();

    //////////////

    function activate(){
       getVersions();
    }

    function getVersions(){
        dashboardService.getVersions()
                     .then(function(data) {
                        vm.versions = data;
                        return vm.versions;
                     });
    }

}
```

I linked a similar question in the comments and in the answers they also talk about using [$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#!) if you need more than one controller to be aware of any changes to the variable's value in your service.

Comment: Thanks for the response, upon attempting to apply your solution to my code, I still was receiving undefined in my controller. If it works on your end could you make quick Fiddle with the running code so I can cross reference. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually upon changing the vm.syncService to $scope.syncService the code you provided does work thank you.

Comment: That example appears to be using $broadcast and/or $emit (these are $scope methods). See the link in my answer to get a better understanding of how they work.